# How to use correctly iplot of library(ichimoku) in r shiny

Tags: shiny, quantmod

Good evening.
I would like to use the ichimiko package for an interactive visualization in r shiny.
I would like that every time the user choose a sticker, the graphic can change automatically.
When I put the code in the ui interface I get the following error ('cloud not existing').

But if I save the code of the cloud (here stock = "AAPL") before running the shinyApp, the code work Well. I get the graphic but the plot is very great 0

**ichimoku(getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from=start_date, to=end_date, auto.assign=F))-> cloud**

Below is the code.

```
library(ichimoku)
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

start_date <- Sys.Date()-365
end_date <- Sys.Date()

ui <- fluidPage("Stock market",
                titlePanel("Stop market App"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
  textInput("Stock","Input Stock"),
  selectInput("Stock", label = "Stock :", choices = c("DIA",
                                   "MSFT",
                                   "FB",
                                   "AAPL",
                                   "GOOG"), selected = "AAPL", multiple = FALSE),
  actionButton("GO","GO")),
  mainPanel(br(),
  h2(align = "center", strong("ICHIMOKU CLOUD PLOT")),
  iplot(cloud, width = 1000, height = 1000)
)))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  cs <- new.env()
  data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{
    req(input$Stock)
    getSymbols(input$Stock, src = "yahoo", 
               from=start_date, to=end_date, auto.assign=F)
  })
  
  cloud1 <- reactive({
    dt<- data()
    cloud <- ichimoku(dt)
  })
  cloud <- ichimoku(cloud1(), ticker = input$Stock)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

IS it also possible to fix the bslib at the left and down side?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the "iplot()" object in the server and call it in the ui with plotOutput()?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."